# How many CRs (Custom Resources) can a kubernetes cluster handle?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, kubernetes-operator

1. How many CRs of a certain CRD can a k8s cluster handle?
2. How many CRs can a certain controller (or Operator) reconcile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. How many CRs of a certain CRD can a k8s cluster handle?**

As many as your API server's [storage space allows](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#storage):

> Custom resources consume storage space in the same way that ConfigMaps
> do. Creating too many custom resources may overload your API server's
> storage space.
>
> Aggregated API servers may use the same storage as the main API
> server, in which case the same warning applies.

**2. How many CRs can a certain controller (or Operator) reconcile?**

A controller in Kubernetes keeps track of **at least one resource type**. There many built-in controllers in Kubernetes, replication controller, namespace controller, service account controller, etc. Custom Resource definition along with Custom Controller makes the [Operator Pattern](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/). It's hard to tell what is the maximum CR that a given Operator could handle as it would depend on different aspects such as the Operator itself. For example, [this guide](https://01.org/kubernetes/blogs/2020/using-kubernetes-custom-controller-manage-two-custom-resources-designing-akraino-icn-bpa) shows that the Binary Provisioning Agent (BPA) Custom Controller can handle two or more custom resources.

You can find some useful sources below:

- [Custom Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#storage)
- [Operator pattern](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/)
- [Using a Kubernetes custom controller to manage two custom resources](https://01.org/kubernetes/blogs/2020/using-kubernetes-custom-controller-manage-two-custom-resources-designing-akraino-icn-bpa)
- [Kubernetes Custom Resource, Controller and Operator Development Tools](https://admiralty.io/blog/2018/06/27/kubernetes-custom-resource-controller-and-operator-development-tools/)